# How do I re-scale a video taken in portrait mode to fit a UIView?

Tags: swift, video, uicollectionview, scale

I have a UICollectionView **feed** where users can record videos, and the video will be displayed and played in the feed. The video fits the UIView perfectly if the user films in landscape mode. However, if the user films in portrait mode, there are white horizontal bars on the sides, filling the surplus.

> Given the video URL, is there a way to scale the video to fit the UIView in a cell of the UICollectionView?

*Aside*: I would also like to eventually play these videos in-line so they don't play simultaneously. Is there a good framework that I can use to bootstrap this functionality?

A cell in the UICollectionView feed will contain a UIView, which will hold the video player. This is the UIView's class **PlayerViewClass**:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class PlayerViewClass: UIView {

    override static var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return AVPlayerLayer.self
    }

    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer {

        return layer as! AVPlayerLayer
    }

    var player: AVPlayer? {
        get {
            return playerLayer.player
        }

        set {
            playerLayer.player = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Note, the cell **MyCollectionViewCell** has an IBOutlet linked to this UIView:

```
class MyCollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var playerView: PlayerViewClass!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib() 

   //Setup, not relevant

   }

}
```

The Feed's collectionView cellForItemAt indexPath delegate method in the **FeedViewController** is as follows:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

      if let cell = cell as? MyCollectionViewCell {

      ...

      //Configuring the cell

      ...

      //Video player
      let avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: post.fullURL)

      **//TODO: Scale the video to the playerView (UIView)**

      //Setting cell's player
      cell.playerView.playerLayer.player = avPlayer

      //Play
      cell.playerView.player?.play()

    }
    return cell
  }
```

**Alternatively**, could I perhaps set `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize { }` so the cell view fits the size of the video according to its dimensions?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `videoGravity` property of `AVPlayerLayer`. Set it to `resizeAspectFill` so video will fill the cell, however video will be cutted on the sides, so make sure it is ok for you.

Comment: Thanks so much! Is there any way for the video not to be cut off or is this not possible given the dimensions of portrait vs. landscape? That is, can I change `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize { }` to resize the cell's view based on the size of the video?

Comment: @SergioCharles It's all depends on what UI you want to achieve. You can use `sizeForItemAt ` method but I'm not sure if you will be satisfied with result. I can suggest you to subclass `UICollectionViewLayout` class instead. It is more flexible.

Comment: Thanks! Using, `UICollectionViewLayout`, how would I format the video cells so I get a result similar to an Instagram feed with video cells?

Comment: @SergioCharles primo, Instagram uses square views to display videos. Your portrait videos will not fill it anyway without `videoGravity ` with `resizeAspectFill ` value. Secundo, you can try to look around internet, I'm sure you will find good tips or you can ask another question here, since it is absolutely different question which require detailed explanation